# Is it possible to group child nodes based on element name in xslt 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following input (a snippet of the xml):

```
<prompt>
    This is a sentence with <b>bold</b>.
    <p>
        This is in a paragraph element.
    </p>
    This is a <i>second</i> <b>sentence</b>.
</prompt>
```

I have a template which matches on `p` and `prompt`. In that template, it wraps the content in `<PARAGRAPH>` elements.

For the above example, the desired output is:

```
<PARAGRAPH>
    This is a sentence with bold.
</PARAGRAPH>
<PARAGRAPH>
    This is in a paragraph element.
</PARAGRAPH>
<PARAGRAPH>
    This is a second sentence.
</PARAGRAPH>
```

Is there somehow a way to break up the content of prompt into groups based on element names? Specifically groups under element names of non-p and p?

I've been reading about the Muenchian grouping strategy in XSLT but cannot see how to apply or if it's even possible to do so. Maybe I should be approaching this another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there somehow a way to break up the content of prompt into groups
>   based on element names?

That's not really what you show us - your groups are based on the `<p>` element serving as a divider between **text** nodes.

> I've been reading about the Muenchian grouping strategy in XSLT but
>   cannot see how to apply or if it's even possible to do so.

It's possible - but in this case it's not at all trivial. Try it along these lines:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="group-by-divider" match="prompt/node()[not(self::p)]" use="count(preceding-sibling::p)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="prompt"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="prompt">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="group"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::p)][count(. | key('group-by-divider', count(preceding-sibling::p))[1]) = 1]" mode="group">
    <PARAGRAPH>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('group-by-divider', count(preceding-sibling::p))"/>
    </PARAGRAPH>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p" mode="group">
    <PARAGRAPHx>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </PARAGRAPHx>
</xsl:template>

<!-- suppress nodes other than through the key -->
<xsl:template match="node()" mode="group"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You may want to add some white-space management to make it more pretty.

Comment: This is great thanks! I had to modify the key to account for other prompt nodes existing, which I know I didn't specify in my original post. Just in case others wanted to know, I counted the number of previous prompt nodes and concatenated with the count preceding-sibling. `concat(count(preceding-sibling::p), '-', count(preceding::prompt))` Maybe a better way to do this? Anyway, thanks for the help! Definitely got me through this hurdle. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="prompt">
<yourRoot>
<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="name() = 'p'">
<PARAGRAPH>
<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
</PARAGRAPH>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</yourRoot>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 1.0. It also says so in the title.

Comment: Thanks, I will not ignore XSLT version  in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The following stylesheet produces a string delimited by the `<p>` elements by applying templates and then splits that string into `<paragraph>` elements with a recursive template.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="'|'"/>

    <xsl:template match="prompt">
        <xsl:call-template name="split-to-paragraph">
            <xsl:with-param name="txt">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="prompt/node()">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="prompt/p" priority="1">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($delimiter, . ,$delimiter)"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split-to-paragraph">
        <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
        <xsl:param name="txt"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($txt, $delimiter)">
                <PARAGRAPH>
                  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(
                                         substring-before($txt, $delimiter))"/>
                </PARAGRAPH>
                <xsl:call-template name="split-to-paragraph">
                   <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                   <xsl:with-param name="txt" 
                                   select="substring-after($txt, $delimiter)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <PARAGRAPH>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($txt)"/>
                </PARAGRAPH>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1, nice. BTW, you can remove the delimiter param on the recursive call.

Comment: I probably should have used a different variable name to disambiguate the global `xsl:param` from the template `xsl:param`, but intentionally asserted the current `$delimiter` value so that the recursive template would retain the value that was originally sent in the first call to the template (which could have a different value, rather than rely on the default behavior).